# Push multiple json array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have 2 json object. i need to push inside array like this. Later i need to store the complete object in `localstorage`

```
function(cObj,bObj) { }
```

First array i should get.

```
object
        localArray: Array[2]
            cObj
                ....
            bObj
```

Again when the function is called, i should get

```
object
        localArray: Array[2]
            cObj
                ....
            bObj
        localArray: Array[2]
            cObj
                ....
            bObj
```

This is what i am doing.

```
localObj = {}
localObj.localArray = [];   


localObj.localArray.push(cObj,bObj);
localStorage.localObj = JSON.stringify(localObj);
```

How to store the complete object in localstorage?

Comment: you can only store string in local storage

Comment: "_Again when the function is called, i should get..._" Keys in an object are unique, hence the structure shown isn't possible.

Comment: How do i push 2 objects into an `localArray`

Comment: push them individually

Comment: I want to group them cobj,bobj everytime when i push..

Comment: or your could do `localObj.localArray.push.apply(localObj.localArray, [cObj,bObj])` to apply the `push` function to an array of elements onto the array

Comment: No this will just push elements one after the other.. it will be like inside localarray - object0,object1,object2,object3...

Comment: Everytime when i push the two objects should group inside the parent object.. how is it to be acheived?

Comment: what exactly do you want the result to look like? because your keys should be unique otherwise what you want is an array of 2d arrays of objects

Comment: Basically there are two objects coming from the function `cobj,bobj`. I want to push this to an array by group.. So next time when i push i should be able to create new array..  Finally i will have mulitple array inside these arrays, i have 2 respective objects `cobj,bobj`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136209/discussion-between-matarishvan-and-jonathan-portorreal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys in your object should be unique so if you want something like this

```
object
    localArray: Array[2]
        cObj
            ....
        bObj
    localArray: Array[2]
        cObj
            ....
        bObj
```

The closest you're going to get to this, is with an object like that has an array of objects which encompass the key you would originally want to have  repeated that can't be repeated because keys in an object should be unique:

```
cObj = {
  key: value
};

bObj = {
  key: value
};

// your local object would look like this 

{
  data: [
    {
      localArray: [
        cObj,
        bObj
      ]
    },
    {
      localArray: [
        cObj,
        bObj
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

You could then just use the following code to update this object:

```
localObj.data.push({localArray: [cObj,bObj]});
```

And you would use it like this in your function:

```
localObj = {}
localObj.localArrays = [];

localObj.localArrays.push({
  localArray: [cObj, bObj]
});
localStorage.localObj = JSON.stringify(localObj);
```